# Why does my code change when I remove printf() function

Tags: c, compilation, linked-list, printf, computer-science

I'm working on a program that takes in a string from the command line, separates the words where there is a non-alphabetic character, and inserts them into a linked list. So for example, hello1world would be separated into "hello" and "world". However when I comment out the first printf statement (shown below), the program doesn't print out the first word in the linked list. When the printf statement exists, the code works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct _Node {
        char * string;
        struct _Node * next;
} Node;


Node * head = NULL;


int isSeperator(int ch) {
        if(isalpha(ch)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
}


void addToList(char * comp) {

        Node * temp = NULL;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp->string = comp;

        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;    
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

        head = malloc(sizeof(Node));

        int i, j, len, lastPos, compLen;

        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                lastPos = 0;
                char * str;
                str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(argv[i]) + 1);

                strcpy(str, argv[i]);
                strcat(str, "\0");
                len = strlen(str);

                for(j = 0; j < len; j++) {

                        compLen = j - lastPos;
                        char comp[compLen + 1];

                        if(isSeperator(*(str + j)) == 1) {
                                memcpy(comp, &str[lastPos], compLen);
                                strcat(comp, "\0");
                                addToList(comp);

                                lastPos = j + 1;
                        } else {
                                if(j == len - 1) {
                                memcpy(comp, &str[lastPos], compLen + 1);
                                strcat(comp, "\0");
                                addToList(comp);
                                }
                        }
                        //printf("%s \n", head->string);
                }
                printf("%s! \n", head->string);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That happens when you have bugs in your code resulting in Undefined Behaviour. `temp->string = comp;` does not copy the string. It makes every node point to the same `comp` buffer whose contents change on each loop. Furthermore, `comp` only exists within the `for` loop and goes out of scope when that loop completes. So the pointers become invalid and accessing them is UB.

Comment: Use something like `strdup` to make a copy of the string.

Comment: Also does the line `char comp[compLen + 1];` really work on your compiler? I don't believe that should be allowed because compLen isn't a static value.

Comment: @TimSweet That's called a Variable Length Array (VLA) and is specified in C99 and optionally in C11. Most compilers do support it.

Comment: @kaylum thanks! I stand corrected. Anecdotally, Visual Studio 2015 (i.e. the version 140 build tools) doesn't support it for C nor C++ (along with most of C99 and up).

Comment: `strcat(str, "\0");` really does not do anything.  What were you hoping to accomplish with this line of code?

Comment: I haven't looked through your code in detail but if the code runs fine with printf statement then it might be an optimization issue.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(argv[i]) + 1);` --> `malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);`